# Why is u=0 always an unstable fixed point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, limits, dynamical-systems, biology

In the following analysis, I cannot see why $u$ is always an unstable fixed point. Calculating $f'(u)= 2R_{0}u-R_{0}-\ln(u)-1 $ at $ u=0 : -R_{0}-1 $ and this in fact suggests that u is a stable fixed point.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: $\ln u$ at $u=0$?

Comment: Hint: How do you determine the type of a fixed point in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the component $\ln u$ of the formula is not defined at $u=0$ we know that $$\lim_{u>0,~ u\to 0}u\ln u=0$$ so that the ODE is defined at $u=0$ with $f(0)=0$ in this continuous continuation. We also know that $\ln u$ diverges towards $-\infty$ for $u\to 0$ so that this term dominates in the factor $R_0(1-u)+\ln u$. Which means that on some interval $(0,\omega)$ this factor will be negative and the full right side $f(u)=-u(R_0(1-u)+\ln u)$ thus positive. Any solution that starts in that interval is monotonically increasing, moving away from zero, which is the characterization of an unstable point.

---

To get a qualitative idea of the way solutions behave close to $0$, reduce the ODE to the terms that are dominant for $u\approx 0$, 
$$u'=-u\ln u,~~u(0)=u_0\approx 0$$ of the dominant terms. By separation one finds
$$
-dt=\frac{du}{u\ln u}= \frac{d(\ln u)}{\ln u}=d(\ln|\ln u|)\\~\\
\ln|\ln u(t)|-\ln|\ln u_0|=-t\implies \ln u(t)=\ln(u_0)e^{-t},~~u(t)={u_0}^{e^{-t}}
$$
which moves $\ln u(t)$ from the very large negative value $\ln u_0$ towards zero, that is, from the very small values of $u_0$ towards $1$, away from zero.

---

You can find a quasi-explicit form of the second root besides $u=1$ using the Lambert-W function, as
$$
0=R_0(1-u)+\ln u\iff -R_0ue^{-R_0u}=-R_0e^{-R_0}
$$
which gives the second solution as $u=-\frac1{R_0}W_k(-R_0e^{-R_0})$ with branch index $k=-1$, $u>\frac1{R_0}$ for $R_0< 1$ and $k=0$, $u<\frac1{R_0}$ for $R_0>1$.

Comment: Thanks this makes a lot of sense! However, I'm not quite able to follow the separation in the second line. Would you mind showing that part in a bit more detail?

Comment: $$\int\frac{du}{u\ln u}=\int \frac{d(\ln u)}{\ln u}=\ln|\ln u|+C.$$ Alternatively, use $(\ln u)'=\frac{u'}{u}=-\ln u$ which has the form $y'=-y$ with the obvious exponential solution.

Comment: Why is $u=lnu$ ?

Comment: @chloeloughan : Where? Did you mean the substitution $y=\ln(u)\iff u=e^y$, $u'=e^yy'=uy'$?

Comment: Solving $u'=-u\ln u$ is quite unnecessary (and frankly, not the recommended approach) to determine the type of the fixed point $u=0$. Likewise for the case $u'=-R_0u(1-u)-u\ln u$ the OP is asking about.

Comment: @Did : That is what the last sentence is about. And some people it might help to have a better idea on the asymptotic behavior.

Comment: Then all this could be said more simply and more rigorously, pointing at the right tools and at the right results: $f(u)=-R_0u(1-u)-u\ln u$ is $0$ at $u=0$ and positive on some interval $(0,w)$ with $w>0$ hence $u=0$ is an unstable fixed point.

Comment: but isn't ln0 not defined?

Comment: Yes, see the first two sentences in this modified answer. $f(0)=0$ in the continuation of the given expression to $u=0$.

Answer (score -1):

$\ln 0$ isn't zero, it's undefined.

(But $\ln u$ tends to $-\infty$ as $u \to 0^+$, while $u \ln u \to 0$).

Comment: To be unstable does it not need to be >0 rather than =0?

Comment: @chloeloughan: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Why did you mention that $ulnu ->0 $ ? What does this have to do with the evaluation of stability?

Comment: If you want to say that $u=0$ is an equilibrium to begin with, you need that the right-hand side of the ODE is zero for $u=0$. But the expression is *undefined* for $u=0$, because it contains the term $\ln u$! So one should really specify that one extends the function in the right-hand side by continuity, so that its value at $u=0$ is defined as its limit as $u \to 0^+$. Unless this is done, it's meaningless to even start taking about $u=0$.